# CoCreateInstance returns E_NOINTERFACE from COM service (service restart fixes it)

Tags: c++, com, vbscript, out-of-process

Once in a while, a COM service that I've implemented will get into a state where my C++ client application will start failing to create the COM object due to an `E_NOINTERFACE` error. The client application is a one-time run (non-persistent) .exe that I run frequently.

To begin with, the COM service will be working fine most of the time, but all of a sudden `CoCreateInstance()` would start returning `E_NOINTERFACE`. To add to the confusion, a VBScript that I wrote continues to run succesfully and creates the COM object without any problem.

If I restart the COM service, all will be back to normal and my C++ application will start working again.

Below are the C++ and VBScript snippets that I run.

**C++**

```
ISampleCom *MyComObj;
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

// Create COM object
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleCom, 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_ISampleCom, (void**)&MyComObj);
if(FAILED(hr))
    printf("\r\nFailed to create COM object.");
```

**VBScript**

```
dim version
set mycomobj = CreateObject("MyCom.Sample")

mycomobj.GetVersion(version)
```

Comment: Attach a debugger to the server when it starts failing.

Comment: Would anything even reach the service if the client is getting E_NOINTERFACE at CoCreateInstance()? It seems like COM is not even recognizing it as an interface that exists on the system.

Comment: What happens if you change the code so that it passes id of `IUnknown` into `CoCreateInstance()` and then uses `QueryInterface()` to retrieve  the interface of interest?

Comment: @ykay, perhaps that object creates tearoff interface pointers for `ISampleCom`, but somehow they're not being released. The VBScript may work all the time because that same object doesn't create tearoff interface pointers for `IDispatch`.